# the weights remain the same, even after training

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I am a beginner in machine learning. I am trying to train a 2 layered fully connected neural network. But after I complete the training, the weights and the biases are pretty much the same as before training. I am initialling them with random numbers.

I also noticed that my cost function is returning the same value every time.

```
def neural_network_model(data,weights):
    tenz = tf.placeholder('float',[1,31])
    var = tf.Variable(tf.ones([1]))
    hidden_1_layer = {
        "weights":tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([counter,max_len])),
        "biases":tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([max_len,max_len]))
    }
    #hidden_1_layer['weights'] = weights
    output_layer = {
        "weights":tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([31,2])),
        "biases":tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2]))
    }
    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data,hidden_1_layer['weights']) , hidden_1_layer['biases'])
    tenz = tf.transpose(tf.expand_dims(tf.diag_part(l1),1))
    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(tenz,output_layer['weights']),output_layer['biases'])
    output = tf.nn.relu(l2)
    weights = tf.sub(weights,hidden_1_layer['weights'])
    return output,weights
prediction,weights = neural_network_model(x,weights)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction,y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1).minimize(cost)
```

Comment: But is this 31 inputs -> one output? If so the cost function shouldn't be softmax, it should be mse or something along those lines. (Comment added for user djk47463)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include more info, rather than put it in comments.

Comment: Is your cost decreasing?